# No route found in rspec test for an existing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

rake routes shows:

```
 estimate_location GET      /estimate/location/:id(.:format)   estimate/location#show
```

And my rspec test:

```
it 'should re-direct to location/new from show' do
  e = FactoryGirl.create :estimate
  get estimate_location_path e
  expect(response.status).to eq(302)
end
```

And the console says:

```
   Failure/Error: get estimate_location_path e
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"estimate/location", :action=>"/estimate/location/1"}
```

This does not make sense to me.  There is a route, I passed an object (which Rails smartly grabs the ID from), but it's saying there is no such path??

Comment: Is the routes you're trying to request from an engine or just namespaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are writing a controller spec (which rails calls functional tests)

In these tests the `get`, `post` etc methods expect the first argument to be the name of the action and the second a hash of options - they bypass routing (although they do check that the action is routable). You would instead do

```
get :show, id: e.id
```

In integration tests (request specs or feature specs) on the other hand you would use an actual path (and depending on the setup you would use either `visit` or `get`, `post` etc but they'd be different `get` methods)

Comment: It was the syntax that got me.  Apparently Rspec is very strict about the syntax when doing a get like this.  Thanks - this particular version finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your test

```
it 'should re-direct to location/new from show' do
  let(:estimate) {FactoryGirl.create(:estimate)}

  before {get estimate_location_path(estimate)}

  expect(response.status).to eq(302)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The app using the Engine had no issues mapping the routes but rspec could not find the route.

Hours later, I rewrote my routes file from:

`Authentication::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      post '/auth_token/:id', to: 
Authentication::Api::V1::AuthTokenController.action(:create), as: :auth_token
    end
  end
end`

to

`Authentication::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      post '/auth_token/:id' => 'auth_token#create', as: :auth_token
    end
  end
end`

It seems rspec wasn't smart enough to reverse engineer the way the route was written in the first snippet back to the controller.