# rails rspec No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm trying to test my routes (they work fine for real requests) and get this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
    No route matches {:action=>"api/login", :controller=>"login", :email=>"a@a.com", :password=>"super_secure"}
```

I've looked at a bunch of similar questions but could not find a precise answer for my problem.

My route is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

post 'api/login' => 'login#email_login'
```

and my test is

```
describe LoginController do
  it 'works fine' do
    password = 'super_secure'
    salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt.to_s
    hash_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt).to_s
    user_login = FactoryGirl.create(:user_login, user_hash: hash_password, salt: salt, email: 'a@a.com')
    post 'api/login', password: password, email: user_login.email
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

Finally my `LoginController` is:

```
class LoginController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery except: [:email_login], with: :exception

  def email_login
    auth = UserLogin.auth(params[:email], params[:password])
    return render text: 'unauthorized', status: 401 unless auth[:user]
    return render json: auth
  end
end
```

I've tried different ways to pass the data to the post method but they all failed...

It you have a clue, that would help!

Comment: This sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551578/no-route-found-in-rspec-test-for-an-existing-route/28557742#28557742 to me

Comment: Thanks, I moved the tests from the spec/controller to spec/requests and it magically worked. If you add your comment as a reply I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In your test, try adjusting your path, like this:

```
post '/api/login', password: password, email: user_login.email
```

Comment: It unfortunately returns the same error